# How to "mark" or "highlight" "tag" different lines in Sublime Text 2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sublimetext2

I'm using Sublime Text 2 to write a view in Rails.  I'm using an existing view as a template to start off with, but obviously I will have to change the variables.

I want to "highlight" or "mark" or "tag" or "something" the wrong variables so I can remember to change them later.  Right now the variables are working, but referring to the wrong thing.  I want to change only one variable at a time so that I don't break the whole thing at once.

I've looked at the documentation for "mark" and "tag" but those commands seem to be for other purposes.  When I look at "highlight" references that seems to exclusively refer to highlighting occurrences of a particular word.

Any ideas?  Thanks very much.

Comment: You could probably put something in your language's syntax highlighting file to recognize a tag you put in the code, but that seems like a really hack-y way to do it.

Comment: I not of really hack-y skill yet.  Hopefully someone has already come up with something.

Comment: if sublime text can highlight search results, you could hack together a regular expression, matching your variable names.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you don't want to simply mass-rename all instances of a particular variable, class name, or whatever at once. If you do, just use **`Find -> Replace...`**, type in what you want to replace in the top field, what you want to replace it with in the bottom field, hit <kbd>Replace</kbd> a few times to ensure you're replacing what you want (especially if you're using a regex find), then hit <kbd>Replace All</kbd> to take care of the whole shebang.

If that's **not** what you want to do, and you'd like to somehow just highlight all occurrences of a certain word or pattern, then check out the [`PersistentRegexHighlight`](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/PersistentRegexHighlight) plugin, available via [Package Control](https://sublime.wbond.net). Once installed, copy the contents of **`Preferences -> Package Settings -> PersistentRegexHighlight -> Settings-Default`** to **`... -> Settings-User`**, then close the Default tab. Edit the `"regex"` section to look something like this:

```js
"regex": [
    {
        "pattern": "config",
        "color_scope": "invalid",
        "underline": false
    }
],
```

This sets up a watcher that looks for any instance of the word `config` in a newly-opened file, and highlights it using the `invalid` scope, which should be in just about every color scheme.  `"underline": false` means that the found text is highlighted instead of underlined. Full options and examples are available at the plugin's link I gave above. The `"regex"` array can contain multiple rule sets, just put a comma `,` after the closing brace `}` (except for the last one) and start your next rule on the next line.